# ng-grid in from tag with run at server in aspx page

Tags: ng-grid

i am calling the ajax function on click of button it  returns the json data and i am    passing the data to the main.js script file(controller) its getting the data and binding the data to the ng-grid, the question here is whne i put the ng-grid in the from tag it does not dispaly the data

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#mybutton").click(function () {

                var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById("wrap")).scope(); // to get  access all the varibales defined in the contoller
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "Website/Nggrid.asmx/GetDataForNgGrid",
                        success: function (result) {
                            //                        console.log(result);

                            var fd = JSON.parse(result); //parsing the json string
                            scope.updateMessage(fd);
                            alert("hi");
                        },
                        error: function (xmlhttprequest, Status, thrownError) {

                            alert(thrownError.toString());
                            alert(thrownError);
                        }
                    });



                });
            });
        });

    </script>
```

this is the function i am calling  when the user clicks on button

```
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <%--<form id="form1" runat="server">--%>
    <div id="wrap" class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions">
    </div>
    <button id="mybutton">
        Try it</button>
    <%-- </form>--%>
</body>
```

this is the main.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.myData = [];
    $scope.updateMessage = function (_s) {
        $scope.myData = _s;
        // $scope.Enable = true;
    };

    $scope.gridOptions = {
        data: 'myData',
        columnDefs: [
     { field: 'Status', displayName: 'Status', width: "*" }

           ]
    };
});
```

my question is here that  when i put ng-grid in the from tag it wont show the data, please give the suggestion on this

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="wrap" class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions">
    </div>
    <button  id="mybutton">
        Try it</button>
 </form>
```